# how to set default font and font style in cocoa app?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, fonts, nsview

My app has all different kind of NSViews, including NSTabView, NSButton, NSTextField, NSPopupButton and so on.

I would like to change all display text to a certain font and with certain font style.

is there anyway to set the default font and font style in cocoa app?

I have tried:
[How to loop through subviews in order to get the text of NSTextViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352811/how-to-loop-through-subviews-in-order-to-get-the-text-of-nstextviews)

however it doesn't work with NSTabView and NSButton.

I think that there must be an easy to do so, it's just I don't know what it is.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a built in way to do this (ie. by setting a key in Info.plist). You really do need to go through all the controls in your app, one way or another, and set a custom font for them. There are a few possible approaches. One is to use a custom subclass for all the controls for which you need to use a custom font. The subclass can be really minimal, it just needs to set the correct font upon initialization, possibly preserving other font attributes (size, color, etc.) setup in Interface Builder. Another option is to do as you've suggested and go through each subview in your app, check to see if it responds to `-setFont:`, and set your custom font if it does. I've used the first approach (subclass) with good success.